# How did I get a Test net

Tags: testnet

I was downloading bitcoin for the first time and during the last 3 minutes while doing some other work on my computer, something about an interruption flashed and then it looked as if nothing had ever happened and it was not downloading. I went to the file I had saved it in and there was a Bitcoin Core [test net] so I clicked on it and it is now synching. Is this normal? Any advice? I was told to start the download again?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core's installer will also setup a shortcut for testnet. Testnet is a different blockchain and network specifically for testing. This is normal and expected behavior, but there is no reason for you to be using testnet. You should stop Bitcoin Core and just use the normal launcher.